# Multiple Select using AssetUrlSelector in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, multiple-select

I have tried to make the AssetUrlSelector in Sharepoint to allow MultipleSelect, but without any luck. Has someone any good solutions how to make this possible.